# Why does opacity not behave correctly for this div in Chrome 30 on OS X?

Tags: css, google-chrome, opacity

After updating to `Chrome 30.0.1599.69` on Mac OS X, suddenly certain pages on my website aren't rendering correctly.

Page with incorrect behavior:

http://www.istorical.com/recent?page=2

After the content inside a certain div goes past a certain height, it's all invisible. If you scroll down far enough you'll see the main content just disappears at a certain point. The div has `opacity: 0.92`. If I set the `opacity: 1`, it displays just fine.

This bug only occurs on this latest version of Chrome for Mac. It has displayed fine everywhere up until this point, and displays correctly on Windows and in Firefox and Safari for Mac.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hICY.jpg

Edit: I've discovered that this bug only occurs when a youtube or vimeo video iframe is present inside of the div with opacity: 0.92. If I delete the iframes from the DOM in Chrome dev tools, the missing content appears.

So it would seem it's an issue of incompatibility between embedded videos and transparent divs.

Comment: I don't see it... I went to your page and scrolled down... my thoughts are that you have an animate function happening. Maybe that is erroring out and not reducing the opacity.

Comment: Are you on Chrome 30 for Mac OS X?

Comment: I checked the same page from the screen shot. I don't see anything. Could be a flow collapse though. try giving the contents parent container a css property  of { overflow: hidden}

Comment: How about this page: http://www.istorical.com/recent?page=2 Can you see embedded youtube videos if you scroll down far enough?

Comment: I can confirm seeing the issue in Chrome 30 on Windows 7. The browser hangs for a bit as I scroll down. I have always seen performance issues across browsers when there are plugins/iframes scattered about the page.